# On click add class via core JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

How should I transfer this code in CORE JS file so **no jQuery at all**:

```
$('#menu-icon-trigger').click(function () {
    $('menu-icon').toggleClass('is-clicked');
});
```

Comment: Just for fun... If you would ever want to know the difference between jQuery and JavaScript, the following test demonstrates it very nicely: http://jsperf.com/javascript-toggle-performance/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to replicate jquery toggle class into JS is as follows:

```
function controlClass() {

    document.querySelector('menu-icon').classList.toggle('is-clicked');

}

document.querySelector('#menu-icon-trigger').addEventListener('click', controlClass);
```

Comment: You could take this a step further and just attach an "onclick" event to the HTML element that it occurs on instead of attaching the event listener.

Comment: Can you edit your post and attach some more code. Or put it on jsfiddle so that it can be tested